# Vectors In Implicit Form

Tags: vector-spaces

Say I have two vectors in the x,y,z plane in implicit form, where i,j,k are the basis vectors. How do I find out the  angle between the two lines?

I was considering expressing the two vectors in explicit form using two unknown parameters for each equation, once in tho form using the scalar product, but this lead to a dead end as I can't get rid of the parameters.

Then I was considering expressing the two vectors in explicit form and then setting the two unknown parameters as 0, then using the scalar product on those two vectors I can find the angle between them as there is no unknown parameters in the way.

Is that the correct method or have I got it wrong?

Comment: Are your data the equations of two lines or the components of two vectors ? What are the _two unknown parameters_ ?

Answer (score 1):

You use only the direction vectors of the the two vectors in explicit form.